# Open specific activity when notification clicked in background

Tags: android, notifications

There are two types of messages in FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging):

Display Messages: These messages trigger the onMessageReceived() callback only when your app is in foreground

Data Messages:
 Theses messages trigger the onMessageReceived() callback even if your app is in foreground/background/killed

When the notification is received in foreground i am able to open the specific activity on notification press but when the notification is received in **background** i can t handle the notification press(it launches automatically the main activity)

I did some search and found :

I added these intent-filter to my notification activity:

```
<activity android:name="com.mahdi.tiger.alahedclubnewtesting.activity.News_description"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.mahdi.tiger.alahedclubnewtesting.activity.News_description"></action>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

but it doesn t work..

I found also :

```
When your app is in the background, Android directs notification messages to the system tray. A user tap on the notification opens the app launcher by default.
```

So what should i do ? i want when the notification is received in background to handle the click and open my specific activity.

This is the code i am using:

```
    public class myFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

        private static final String TAG = "FirebaseMessageService";
        Bitmap bitmap;

        /**
         * Called when message is received.
         *
         * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
         */
        @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
            // There are two types of messages data messages and notification messages. Data messages are handled
            // here in onMessageReceived whether the app is in the foreground or background. Data messages are the type
            // traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received here in onMessageReceived when the app
            // is in the foreground. When the app is in the background an automatically generated notification is displayed.
            // When the user taps on the notification they are returned to the app. Messages containing both notification
            // and data payloads are treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always sends notification
            // messages. For more see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
            //
            Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

            // Check if message contains a data payload.
            if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
            }

            // Check if message contains a notification payload.
            if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

                String title=remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
                String body=remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
                String action=remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();



                sendNotification2(title,body,action);
            }

            //The message which i send will have keys named [message, image, AnotherActivity] and corresponding values.
            //You can change as per the requirement.
            String text = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
            //message will contain the Push Message
            String message = remoteMessage.getData().get("message");
            //imageUri will contain URL of the image to be displayed with Notification
            //If the key AnotherActivity has  value as True then when the user taps on notification, in the app AnotherActivity will be opened.
            //If the key AnotherActivity has  value as False then when the user taps on notification, in the app MainActivity will be opened.
            String TrueOrFlase = remoteMessage.getData().get("AnotherActivity");

            //To get a Bitmap image from the URL received
            sendNotification(message, text,TrueOrFlase);

        }


        /**
         * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
         */

        private void sendNotification(String messageBody,String text, String TrueOrFalse) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Slider_description.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.putExtra("AnotherActivity", TrueOrFalse);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ahed_me)
                    .setContentTitle(text)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentText(messageBody)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
        }
}
```

NOTE: i am using Firebase console to send notification.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the name of the activity you are trying to launch ?

Comment: News_description activity

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of testing I found this.

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/MyFirebaseMessagingService.java

The interesting part for you.

> There are two types of messages data messages and notification
>   messages. Data messages are handled  here in onMessageReceived whether
>   the app is in the foreground or background. Data messages are the type
>   traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received
>   here in onMessageReceived when the app is in the foreground. When the
>   app is in the background an automatically generated notification is
>   displayed. When the user taps on the notification they are returned to
>   the app. Messages containing both notification and data payloads are
>   treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always sends
>   notificationmessages.

- For more see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

If you want full control on the notification you need to send data message. You can not use the firebase console to do it from my understanding.

Comment: No no it doesn t matter because i have recently changed Slider_description to News_description

Comment: @MahdiHraybi did you try with data message ?

Comment: I have found the solution thanks @Kevin but now i am facing another problem is that when sending another notification ..it replaces the first one

Comment: What was the solution sending notification via server ?

Comment: Sorry @Kevin i didn t see your edited answer.
By the way now all my questions has been answered using this :
https://github.com/miskoajkula/Fcm

Check it u can send notifications to all users + the notifications doesn t replace the before one

Thanks for your effort

Comment: Firebase notification is just for testing..if u want to do some more stuff send notification using your app server (use the scripts in github link)
Cheers